# MVC head components

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, head

I'm quite new to MVC. In my website I use a layout for all the views and I was wondering how could I add links to certain .css files.

What I mean is that if I add them in the _layout.cshtml, all HTML files will have that link although some of them don't need it, which could lead to performance issues??

How could I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layout page works like a master page. You can define a section in the partial view and then render it in the layout page:

**Define a section named (Styles) in the view that needs (yourView_style.css) file to be rendered:**

```
@section Styles {
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Styles/yourView_style.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}
```

**In (_layout.cshtml) render the (Styles) section:**

```
<head>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Styles/main.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @RenderSection("Styles", false)
</head>
```